# Angular filter that compares an array of strings in ng-repeating objects - with an array of strings, and filters out objects that do not match

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

This Angular filter is being passed an array of objects used in an ng-repeat (item in items).

```
    [{
        title: "Star Wars",
        categories: ["Adventure", "Family"]
    }, {
        title: "Star Search",
        categories: ["Realty", "Fantasy"]
    }, {
        title: "Star Trek",
        categories: ["Sci-Fi", "Fantasy"]
    }]
```

And an array of strings (categoriesFiltered)

```
    ["Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]
```

What would be the best way to iterate through the *items* in the ng-repeat and compare the *categories* array... to the *categoriesFiltered* array, and push the *items* that match to the new *filtered* array?

This is how far I have come

```
categoryFilter.filter('filterCategories', function () {
    return function (items, categoriesFiltered) {
        var filtered = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < items[i].categories; j++) {
                if (filtered.indexOf(items[i].categories[j]) === -1) {
                    filtered.push(items[i]);
                };
            };
        };
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RecWR6urjztt8FhRqrsE)...

Comment: Approach appears reasonable...is it working? Some might use `Array.prototype.filter()` or `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: I will look into those directions... Thank you @charlietfl

Comment: no real need if it works...for loops work well...is there a problem or not? If this is just a code review question is better to ask those on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Questions here are meant for real problems

Comment: Apologize @charlietfl - I did not answer your question, the for loops are not working properly

Comment: can you put a simple demo together for this in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)? Doesn't need any css or anything fancy

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl... lesson learned, will always attach a plunker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. Your returned `filtered` array falls outside the returned function, it should be inside.
2. You're not checking for `items[i].categories.length` in your `for` loop condition.
3. You're using the wrong array to check the `indexOf`.
4. I'm assuming your `categoriesFiltered` example was a typo looks like `["Adventure", "Sci-Fi"]` because `[{"Adventure", "Sci-Fi"}]` is invalid javascript.

Try this:

```
categoryFilter.filter('filterCategories', function () {
    return function (items, categoriesFiltered) {
        var filtered = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < items[i].categories.length; j++) {
              if (categoriesFiltered.indexOf(items[i].categories[j]) > -1) {
                filtered.push(items[i]);
              }
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
```

Comment: 1. Yes it is outside... edited. 2. Checking with logging. 3. Checking with Google. 4. Yes it was a typo... edited. Thank you @user2341963

Comment: Yes @user2341963... I see where 2 and 3 were wrong. The filter is working now, nicely put - Thank you